# google quick actions self testing

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I have taken examples from developers.google.com/gmail/actions/getting-started
and sent them from me@gmail.com too me@gmail.com.

I verified the source with www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ and it correctly recognizes the quick action.

I used a mail client to imbed the proper html syntax...
upon receipt in gmail I verified with "Show original" that the mail client didn't mess with the raw html syntax.

Gmail uses spf authentication which was verified by the presence of "mailed-by:  gmail.com" in the drop down user interface.

despite all of this the quick action fails to show...
I have even duplicated the syntax, character by character, of an email from google calendar which does show a quick action... still no quick action...

developers.google.com/gmail/actions/testing-your-schema

> All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account
>   ignore the registration requirements and can be used for self-testing.

Self testing has never succeeded.
How do I test quick actions?

Comment: I have the same problem, quick actions are not showing up

Comment: I edited the tags b/c the [tag:quickaction] is about iOS not about [Gmail actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview). It's worth to note that Google changed the referred URLs. Now they start with `https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/`